# Search by a keyword instead of a tag

Tags: support, tags, search

I noticed some users fail to tag their questions properly. They use specific tags instead of general ones. E.g. using `angularjs-directive` without `angularjs`. It's easy to see that not many people will help them, as it would be difficult to find them in the first place. Luckily (!) some add "*AngularJS*" in the title, which gave me the idea to search for this keyword instead of the tag.

**The problem is** that when I search for `angularjs` it automatically assumes it's a tag and changes it to `[angularjs]`. With this, it becomes impossible to find people with the issue described earlier.

Shouldn't there be an option to **search keywords and tags separately**?

Comment: Looks like adding a * to the query is a workaround: [https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=angularjs*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=angularjs*)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use quotes

> [`"angularjs"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22angularjs%22)

that prevents the word to be considered as a tag.

and then you can also search for [`"angularjs" -[angularjs] is:q`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22angularjs%22+-%5Bangularjs%5D+is%3Aq) to find the questions that don't have the tag.